# How to create a tensorflow serving client for the 'wide and deep' model?

Tags: java, tensorflow, deep-learning, tensorflow-serving

I've created a model based on the 'wide and deep' example (https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/learn/wide_n_deep_tutorial.py).

I've exported the model as follows:

```
  m = build_estimator(model_dir)
  m.fit(input_fn=lambda: input_fn(df_train, True), steps=FLAGS.train_steps)
  results = m.evaluate(input_fn=lambda: input_fn(df_test, True), steps=1)

  print('Model statistics:')

  for key in sorted(results):
    print("%s: %s" % (key, results[key]))

  print('Done training!!!')

  # Export model
  export_path = sys.argv[-1]
  print('Exporting trained model to %s' % export_path)

  m.export(
   export_path,
   input_fn=serving_input_fn,
   use_deprecated_input_fn=False,
   input_feature_key=INPUT_FEATURE_KEY
```

My question is, how do I create a client to make predictions from this exported model?  Also, have I exported the model correctly?

Ultimately I need to be able do this in Java too.  I suspect I can do this by creating Java classes from proto files using gRPC.

Documentation is very sketchy, hence why I am asking on here.

Many thanks!

Comment: Have you looked at [this tutorial](https://tensorflow.github.io/serving/serving_basic.html)? Where did it go wrong?

Comment: Yeah I've looked at this thanks.  This is great if you're using pure tensorflow, but I'm using the tf.contrib.learn api.  I'm not sure how to export and create a client using this api.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote a simple tutorial [Exporting and Serving a TensorFlow Wide & Deep Model](https://github.com/MtDersvan/tf_playground/blob/master/wide_and_deep_tutorial/wide_and_deep_basic_serving.md).

TL;DR

To export an estimator there are four steps:

1. Define features for export as a list of all features used during estimator initialization.
2. Create a feature config using `create_feature_spec_for_parsing`.
3. Build a `serving_input_fn` suitable for use in serving using `input_fn_utils.build_parsing_serving_input_fn`.
4. Export the model using `export_savedmodel()`.

To run a client script properly you need to do three following steps:

1. Create and place your script somewhere in the /serving/ folder, e.g. /serving/tensorflow_serving/example/
2. Create or modify corresponding BUILD file by adding a `py_binary`.
3. Build and run a model server, e.g. `tensorflow_model_server`.
4. Create, build and run a client that sends a tf.Example to our `tensorflow_model_server` for the inference.

For more details look at the tutorial itself.

Answer (score 1):

Just spent a solid week figuring this out. First off, `m.export` is going to deprecated in a couple weeks, so instead of that block, use: `m.export_savedmodel(export_path, input_fn=serving_input_fn)`.

Which means you then have to define `serving_input_fn()`, which of course is supposed to have a different signature than the `input_fn()` defined in the wide and deep tutorial. Namely, moving forward, I guess it's recommended that `input_fn()`-type things are supposed to return an `InputFnOps` object, defined [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/utils/input_fn_utils.py).

Here's how I figured out how to make that work:

```
from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn.utils import input_fn_utils
from tensorflow.python.ops import array_ops
from tensorflow.python.framework import dtypes

def serving_input_fn():
  features, labels = input_fn()
  features["examples"] = tf.placeholder(tf.string)

  serialized_tf_example = array_ops.placeholder(dtype=dtypes.string,
                                                shape=[None],
                                                name='input_example_tensor')
  inputs = {'examples': serialized_tf_example}
  labels = None  # these are not known in serving!
  return input_fn_utils.InputFnOps(features, labels, inputs)
```

This is probably not 100% idiomatic, but I'm pretty sure it works. For now.